# T/F: $\forall \epsilon , \exists \delta \gt 0$ s.t. $\left| f(x)-f(a) \right| \lt \epsilon \implies \left| x-a \right| \lt \delta $

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing, epsilon-delta

**Here's the question:**

Is the following true or false?

There is a function $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ that satisfies the following condition:

For every $a \in \mathbb R $ and $ \epsilon \gt 0 $ there is $\delta \gt 0$ such that $\left| f(x)-f(a) \right| \lt \epsilon \implies \left| x-a \right| \lt \delta $.

**My initial response:**

I said that this is true for any constant function, e.g. $f(x) = 0$. In this case, $\left| f(x)-f(a) \right| = \left|0-0 \right|=0 \lt \epsilon \text{ and} \left| x-a \right|=\left|0-0 \right|=0 \lt \delta $. I know that this doesn't work because in the $\left| x-a \right|$ case, $x$ may not be $0$, obviously. However, this was the last question on a test, so I kind of just guessed because I was running out of time. Now that I've had time to think about it, though, I can't seem to figure it out (i.e., whether or not it's true or false). Any and all help here is appreciated, as always. Thanks.

Comment: How about identity function?

Comment: Right, the constant function doesn't work, because $|f(x) - f(a)|$ would always be zero and knowing that a particular $|x-a| \lt \delta$ could not be deduced from $0 \lt \epsilon$.  Try a different function, one that is simple in its own fashion.

Answer (score 0):

For every $a∈\mathbb{R}$ and $\epsilon > 0$ there is $\delta>0$ such that

$∣f(x)−f(a)∣<\epsilon \Rightarrow |x−a|<\delta$ ,

which is equivalent to  $|x−a| \geq \delta \Rightarrow ∣f(x)−f(a)∣ \geq \epsilon$,

in this case, any unbounded above and below strictly increasing function on $\mathbb{R}$ is enough.

Strictly increasing shows if there are points $x_0, x_1\in\mathbb{R}$ s.t. $f(x_0) \leq f(a) - \epsilon$ and $f(a) + \epsilon \leq f(x_1)$,

then taking $\delta = \max\{|x_0-a|,|x_1-a|\}$, $|x−a| \geq \delta \Rightarrow ∣f(x)−f(a)∣ \geq \epsilon$ is satisfied.

unboundedness above and below shows there is certainly at least such $x_0$ and $x_1$ in $\mathbb{R}$. Therefore that's enough.

Comment: For example $f(x)=x$ and $\delta=\varepsilon$.

Comment: Strictly increasing isn't enough, what about $x/(1+x)$.

Comment: Yes, you definitely need more than strictly increasing.

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong, unbounded is enough. Forgot $a$ was fixed.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, Arch If we take $f(x)=\mathrm{e}^x$, $a<0$ and $\epsilon=1$ we se that there is no such $\delta$. Thus,  is not enough to be unbounded strictly increasing. It seems that a sufficient (and necessary) condition is
$$\lim_{x\to\pm \infty}f(x)=\pm\infty.$$ Edited after read your edit: Of course, any unbounded above and below strictly increasing function satisfies this.

Comment: I was wrong and Andrew's initial thought was right. Thanks for Perdro's clear example. I edited my answer.

Comment: I should clarify that, in my last comment, $\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}f(x)=\pm\infty$ means
$$\lim_{x\to+\infty}f(x)=\pm\infty\text{ and (not or) }\lim_{x\to-\infty}f(x)=\pm\infty$$

Answer (score 0):

I would say any function with a derivative bounded away from zero will work.

E.G. $f(x)=x$, $f(x)=x^3+x$.